Why this oscillatory behavior of $H(z)$ along $H(1+iT)$?
Consider the function
$$ H(z)=z\bigg(1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log n ~K_1~z \log n\bigg) $$
for modified Bessel $K_1$ and let's plot $H(1+iT)$ for $T\in \Bbb R$, with the imaginary part given a phase adjustment by $-\pi/2$ where I used $e^{-i\pi/2}$ to do this.
This is what it looks like:

It sort of reminds me of the behavior Riemann zeta function along $s=1/2+iT$.

Is $H(1+iT)$ with the phase adjustment related to the Riemann zeta or is it unrelated?

I am wondering why this oscillatory behavior appears. Maybe it is characteristic of certain complex functions.
